# Probability of geometric mean being higher than 1/6

Tags: probability

If we choose $2$ numbers from $[0,2]$, independent from each other,what is the probability of their geometric mean being higher than $1/6$?

I have tried calculating using integrals with the following process:

${\sqrt xy} > (\frac {1}{6})$
$xy > (\frac {1}{36})$
and got an integral from it:
 $\int_{0}^{\frac {1}{36}} {\frac {1}{36x}} dx $ which is divergent.

Comment: Where does that integral come from?

Comment: i just tried using lecture notes to solve the question

Comment: @alex581 The result depends on the probability distribution for x and y which you did not define.

Comment: It wasn't specified in the exercise,so maybe it is continuous,but I don't know honestly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

Using the way you went to approach $xy > \frac{1}{36}$

[image]

$$P(GM> \frac{1}{6} ) = \frac{Area (bound \ by \ x=2 \ , y=2, and \ hyperbola)}{Area(square \ by \ axes \ and \ y=2 \ and \ x=2 ) } = \frac{(1)}{(1)+(2)}$$

$$=\frac{4 -[ \frac{2}{72} + \int_{\frac{1}{72}}^{2}\frac{1}{36x}\,dx ]}{4}$$

Comment: Where does the 1/72 on the integral's lower bound come from?

Comment: when you solve the curve $y=\frac{1}{36x}$ with $y=2$, you get $x=\frac{1}{72}$, so terms in the square bracket are [Area of rectangle formed by y axis, x axis, y=2, and x=1/72  +  Area under hyperbola from x=1/72 to x=2  ]

Answer (score 1):

The values of $x$ and $y$, you are interested in, lie in a square $[0; 2] \times [0; 2]$. So you have a chart of $y = \frac{1}{36x}$, and an answer to your problem equals to an area of intersection of an epigraph and a given square divided by an area of a square. Which equals to $\frac{4 - \int_{1/72}^{2}{\frac{1}{36x}} - \frac{2}{72}}{4}$.

Comment: Where does the 2/72 come from?Thanks for the answer

Comment: $x = \frac{1}{72}$ is a point of intersection of a chart $y = \frac{1}{36x}$ with a top edge of a square (that is $y = 2$). So to calculate a desired area we need to separately handle two cases: $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{72}$ and $\frac{1}{72} \leq x \leq 2$. For the first case we just need to find an area of a rectangle with sides equal to $2$ and $\frac{1}{72}$ which is, obviously, $\frac{2}{72}$.

Actually, Saket Gurjar gave you a pretty good figure.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$\sqrt{XY}>1/6$ iff $Y>1/(36 X)$ where $X,Y$ are i.i.d uniform $[0,2]$ random variables. Since $X,Y$ are i.i.d uniform $[0,2]$ it follows that
$$
P((X,Y)\in A)=\frac{m(A\cap [0,2]^2)}{4}
$$
i.e. $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]^2$ (here $m$ means area) and $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$). Letting $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\mid 36xy>1\}$ we have that
$$
P(\sqrt{XY}>1/6)=P(Y>1/(36 X))=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^2\int_{1/36x}^2\, dy\, dx
$$
which you can compute.

Comment: Can you explain the two integrals please?

Answer (score 0):

For definiteness let us assume that the variables $x$ and $y$ are independent and uniformly distributed between $0$ and $2$, and let us calculate the PDF of the geometric mean $g=\sqrt{x y}$ which is given by the integral

$$f(g) = \frac{1}{4} \int_{(0,2)^2} \delta(g - \sqrt{x y})\,dx \,dy\tag{1}$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

Doing the $x$-integral first gives

$$\frac{g}{2 y} \text{ for } y \ge \frac{g^2}{2} \text{ and zero otherwise}\tag{2}$$

Hence the $y$-integral and therefore the PDF become

$$f(g) = \int_{g^2/2}^2 \frac{g}{2 y} \,dy = g \log \left(\frac{2}{g}\right)\tag{3}$$

Hence the probability that $g\ge \frac{1}{6}$ is given by

$$\text{prob}(g \ge \frac{1}{6}) = \int_{\frac{1}{6}}^2 f(g)\,dg = \frac{1}{144} (143-\log (144)) \simeq 0.958543$$

**Discussion**

The first two moments of $f(g)$ are

$$\int_0^2 g f(g) \, dg = \frac{8}{9}$$

$$\int_0^2 g^2 f(g) \, dg = 1$$

$g$ has maximum probabilty determined from $\frac{d}{dg} f(g) = 0$ at $g_{max}=\frac{2}{e} \simeq 0.735759$.

Similarly, we find that the PDF of the geometric mean of three variables of the same kind is given by

$$f_3(g) = \frac{3}{16} g^2 \log ^2\left(\frac{8}{g^3}\right)$$